# Using SFMC to pull content from a API with JSON response

Tags: api, marketing-cloud

Our client has setup a URL which contains product number which returns the below JSON for each product.

Is it possible in SFMC to simply pass into the email creative the productid and it submits an API to grab this JSON data and then only display basic parts (product name, product price, product picture etc?)

Here is the entire code that is pulled back from the URL:

> {"baseProductCode":"P52789915","displayColour":"#00AB84","name":"Men's
>   Slip On Safety Shoe Burke - Black","description":"Men's slip on work
>   shoe  featuring a steel toe, a leather upper for durability and a
>   technical cushioned insock to absorb shock when
>   walking.","ratings":2.3333333333333335,"colourVariants":[{"code":"52789915","name":"Men's
>   Slip On Safety Shoe Burke -
>   Black","sizeVariants":[{"code":"52790010","name":"6","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790027","name":"7","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790034","name":"8","price":"$69","inStock":false},{"code":"52790041","name":"9","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790058","name":"10","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790065","name":"11","price":"$69","inStock":true},{"code":"52790072","name":"12","price":"$69","inStock":true}],"media":[{"standard":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/large/41/21/A814121.jpg","thumbnail":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/thumb/41/21/A814121.jpg"},{"standard":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/large/41/27/A814127.jpg","thumbnail":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/medias/static_content/product/images/thumb/41/27/A814127.jpg"}],"price":"$69","inStock":true}],"features":[{"name":"Materials and Composition","value":["Upper: Leather","Lining: Synthetic","Sole:
>   Synthetic"]},{"name":"Product Features","value":["Leather
>   upper","Steel toe","Technical cushioned insock to absorb shock when
>   walking"]},{"name":"Care Instructions","value":["Machine
>   Washable"]}],"sizeChartUrl":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/size-chart/menshoe","deliveryModes":[{"available":true,"description":"Free for orders over $19. Not available to all stores. Allow 4-10 business
>   days before pickup.","name":"Click +
>   Collect","excludesCountryStore":false},{"available":true,"description":"Free
>   for orders over $75 (excluding large items). Allow 3-10 business days
>   for delivery.","name":"Home
>   Delivery","excludesCountryStore":false},{"available":false,"description":"For
>   apparel only orders.  Not available to all locations. Available for
>   orders placed by 12pm Mon to Fri","name":"Express
>   Delivery","excludesCountryStore":false}],"infoLinks":[{"name":"FAQs","url":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/modal/faqs"},{"name":"Payments
>   + Delivery","url":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/modal/payment-delivery"},{"name":"Refunds
>   + Returns","url":"http://www.ourwebsite.com/modal/refunds-returns"}],"code":"52790027"}

Any help is much appreciated - I can only get it to retrieve the entire HTML page and it doesn't recognise it contains any data - just that it is a HTML string.

Comment: So I have managed to scrape the page off the content whilst ensuring SFMC knows that it is JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to scrape the page off the content whilst ensuring SFMC knows that it is JSON data.

```
%%[ var @Json
set @Json = HTTPGet("https://www.ourwebiste/productid",false,0,@CallStatus) ]%%

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 20}}
     {{.data}}
    { "target" : "@Json" }
     {{/data}}
     Name: {{name}}
     productcode: {{baseProductCode}}
Price: {{price}}
THumbnail: {{thumbnail}}

{{/datasource}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var @dataRow
set @dataRow = AttributeValue("Row1")
set @row2 = AttributeValue("Row2")
set @row3 = AttributeValue("Row3")
set @row4 = AttributeValue("Row4")
set @row5 = AttributeValue("Row5")


]%%

{{.dataobject dataRowVar type=variable}}
   {{.data}}
      {"target":"@dataRow"}
   {{/data}}
{{/dataobject}}

{{.dataobject dataRowVar2 type=variable}}
   {{.data}}
      {"target":"@row2"}
   {{/data}}
{{/dataobject}}
```

This is pulling in the data:

```
{{#each dataRowVar}} {{.datasource dataRowVar type=inline}} 
{{.data}} { "target" : "dataRow" } {{/data}}

{{title}}<br>
{{dateCreated}}<br>
{{description}}

{{/datasource}} {{/each}}


{{#each dataRowVar2}} {{.datasource dataRowVar2 type=inline}} 
{{.data}} { "target" : "Row2" } {{/data}}
{{title}}


{{title}}<br>
{{dateCreated}}<br>
{{description}}


{{/datasource}} 
{{/each}}
```